# multiple clientservice in rosserial?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need multiple service clients on an arduino running rosserial.

In setup() I have:
nh.serviceClient(client1);
nh.serviceClient(client2);

Only the first is connecting. If I swap the order then client2 is the only one called. No error messages in either serial_node.py or by the Arduino.

Anyone get multiple service clients to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39412/multiple-clientservice-in-rosserial?/) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on 2012-07-22**:
Didn't realize I needed to have the ServiceServer running. Without it running it got hung on the first serviceClient and wouldn't continue to the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Didn't realize I needed to have the ServiceServer running. Without it running it got hung on the first serviceClient and wouldn't continue to the second one. punching (Jul 22 '12)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0